# why in perl array value is not listing on dropdown list using html template?

Tags: perl

my perl cgi page dropdown menu doesn;t listing the values . my cgi script

```
use HTML::Template;use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'test.tmpl');
@count = ("abc,xyz,123,test");
print $cgi->start_form(
                        -name => 'mainpage',
                        -method => 'POST',
                        );


$template->param( COUNT => \@count);
print $template->output();
```

my test.tmpl

```
<div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <input name="count" id="countid" type="text" class="validate">
                                <label for="count">count</label>
    <select>
        <TMPL_LOOP NAME="COUNT">
        <option value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=VALUE>"><TMPL_VAR NAME=NAME></option>
        </TMPL_LOOP>
    </select>                                
</div>

in the drop down menu, I am expecting below values. Please suggest if I need to make any change on above code on cgi or html template
abc
xyz
123
test
```

Please find the modified the cgi script values. cgi page doesn;t show the values in the dropdown tab. however in the html page rendered these values

```
$count = [
{ name => 'count1', value => 1 },
{ name => 'count2', value => 2 },
{ name => 'count3', value => 3 },
];

   $template->param(COUNT => [{name => 'count1', value => 1}, {name =>  'count2', value => 2}, {name => 'count3', value => 3}]);

print $template->output, "\n";
```

html page rendered below

```
<div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input name="count" id="countstate" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="count">count</label>
<select>

<option value="1">count1</option>

<option value="2">count2</option>

<option value="3">count3</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array contains a single element: the string `abc,xyz,123,test`. If you want each of those things to be separate elements, you need to create your array differently:

```
@count = ('abc', 'xyz', 123, 'test');
@count = qw(abc xyz 123 test);
```

Update: OK, after reading the docs for [`<TMPL_LOOP>`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template#TMPL_LOOP), it looks like you actually want an [arrayref of hashrefs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES):

```
$count = [
    { name => '???', value => 'abc' },
    { name => '???', value => 'xyz' },
    { name => '???', value => '123' },
    { name => '???', value => 'test' },
];

$template->param(COUNT => $count);
$template->param(COUNT => [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]);  # same thing
```

However, I can't tell from your question which one should be the label and which one should be the value, so I'll leave that as an exercise for you to complete.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.  I am looking for the values only be listed in the drop down menu (abc  xyz  123 test).  view page source those values, however  in the cgi page dropdown tab shows empty. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. The HTML source is correct, but the rendered output isn't?

Comment: yes. html output is correct.  cgi page doesn't  show up those values in the dropdown menu.  I am using the div method for drop down posted my question. Thank you

Comment: OK... so what _is_ the page showing instead? Can you [edit] your question to include the HTML source rendered by the template engine?

Comment: The HTML looks fine. So what do you actually see in the browser? It might be helpful to attach a screenshot at this point. It seems like you most likely have a CSS issue at this point...

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I'll check my CSS  file

Comment: there was an issue in the CSS file . git it fixed. thank you.

Comment: @bsd Excellent! If this answer works for you and solves your problem, you might want to consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).